# Broken tests report with Composer

Tags: android, testing

we are using [Composer](https://github.com/gojuno/composer) 0.6.0 and facing issues with the tests reports: no title nor screenshots appear, just the logcat, for each test.

The following error appears in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at t.value (app.min.js:25)
    at app.min.js:97
    at s (app.min.js:97)
    at h._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (app.min.js:97)
    at h._renderValidatedComponent (app.min.js:97)
    at h.performInitialMount (app.min.js:97)
    at h.mountComponent (app.min.js:97)
    at Object.mountComponent (app.min.js:6)
    at g.mountChildren (app.min.js:97)
    at g._createInitialChildren (app.min.js:97)
```

There is an open [pull request](https://github.com/gojuno/composer/pull/161) but it has been stuck for some months. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

While a new version of the library is released, this fixed the problem for us:

```
sed -i'' -e "s/stacktrace\.length/stacktrace/g" app/build/reports/composer/html-report/app.min.js
```